# How to insert an item into an array that's in an array that's also in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to insert an item into an multidimensional array and I don't know how to do that.

```
    Meteor.users.update(
       { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $push: {profile: { friends: "hey" } }}
    );
```

Comment: Can you show your schema?

Comment: Is `profile` an array of objects or an array of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Meteor.users.update(
   { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $push: {'profile.friends': 'hey'} }
 );
```

Comment: This would work if `profile` is an object and `friends` is a key of that object that refers to an array. It would not work if `profile` is an array.